# How to map a shuffled array in React/Next without causing hydration mismatch error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm building a Next.js site.

I have an array (of famous quotes) and want to randomise these on the page. I'm using lodash to shuffle the array, and then doing a simple map of the items onto the page.

```
import { useMemo } from 'react';
import { shuffle } from 'lodash';
import quotes from '../_config/quotes';

const Quotes = () => {
  const shuffledQuotes = useMemo(() => shuffle(quotes), quotes);
  return (
    <>
      {shuffledQuotes.map((quote, index) => (
        <Quote key={index} quote={quote} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

All straight forward, and it works. But I get lots of errors:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML.
```

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
```

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.
```

I understand the problem and why it is happening - the loaded static content and the hydrated content are different due to the randomisation.

But how do I achieve what I want without causing these errors? What's the "correct" way to shuffle/randomise content on a Next.js site? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `/pages`/ directory then you need to generate the data on the server, you can use either `getStaticProps`  or `getServerSideProps`, `getServerSideProps` would serve you better if you want different quote on every page refresh. Or you can use `revalidate` param for `getStaticProps` to refresh props with an interval.

So it would look something like that:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  return {
    props: {
      quotes: shuffle(quotes)
    },
  }
}
```